# Downloading file using retrofit2

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am trying to download a file using retrofit2. I have following code:

```
@Streaming
@GET
Call<ResponseBody> downloadFile(@Url String fileUrl);
```

I use it like this:

```
final Call<ResponseBody> call = Api.getMediaService().downloadFile(uri.toString());
call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, final Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    copyInputStreamToFile(response.body().byteStream());
                    return null;
                }
            }.execute();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
        }
    });
```

Code executes fine and file gets downloaded but its not streaming i.e by the time `onResponse()` is called, whole data is already downloaded in memory.

How can I download large files using retrofit using streaming?

Answer (score 0):

The code was fine. I had `HttpLoggingInterceptor` added to my `HttpClient` at `HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY` level which was causing whole response to be read in memory for logging purpose.